# i'm using Discord.js to make a bot. This bot saves users into an array to later dm them. i'm getting errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm having an error when I try to pull a user from an array and dm them. My code is:

```js
var userdming = game.user[0];
message.userdming.send('hi');
```

I'm just trying to get it to work so I can add on to it. The error I get is:

````
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined```
````

Comment: You've defined `userdming`, but not set `message.userdming`.

Comment: how do i do that? is there something on the readthedocs?

Comment: No, it's just how JavaScript works. If a property on an object hasn't been set (either explicitly or via prototypes etc.), it doesn't exist. That `TypeError` is telling you you tried to call `undefined.send(...)`, because `message.userdming === undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `userdming` is a user, you can use [user.createDM()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createDM) to create a new DM channel between your bot and the user. Alternatively, you can also use [user.send()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send), which implicitly creates the DM channel.

In your code, you're trying to use `user.send()`. However, you are trying to access `userdming` as a property of `message`, which it is not. It's its own thing, and should be called like this:

```
var userdming = game.user[0];
userdming.send('hi');
```

Comment: i'm still getting errors! @MLarionov `userdming.send('Game Started! Here are you cards!');
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Comment: @Lann4daze what is yur game.user array saving? Discord.js user objects or just IDs? Or maybe even something else?

Comment: My bot saves message.author when they type !join into the array. @Zer0

Comment: Try putting some breakpoints or `console.log` statements in your code so you can see what the values of variables actually are. If `game.user` is empty, `game.user[0]` will be undefined. But if you don't know what `game.user` contains, you have no hope of ever debugging your code.

Comment: @Lann4daze That's an issue with whatever code you have that pushes to game.user, not my answer. If game.user[0] is undefined then game.user is empty. How are you defining and writing to this array?